# iPhone -Core Plot problem

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-plot

In iPhone App I want to implement core plot (vertical bar chart)

In Original code Prject I am getting graph as

[image]

but when same code I am implementing in my App I am getting plot as

[image]

so what things could be wrong?

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any relevant code you could provide?  In particular, did you set your `barWidth` to be too large?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the bar width i could fix my problem.