# CorePlot Remove bar shadow effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, core-plot

In iPhone App i am using core Plot vertical bar chart.

How to Remove shadow effect in Vertical Bars?

Here as shown in figure bars are displaying with shadow

[image]

Here is the code:

CPBarPlot *barPlot = [CPBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPColor colorWithComponentRed:111 green:129  blue:113 alpha:1.0] horizontalBars:NO];

barPlot.shadowColor=NO;

How can I remove this shadow effect?

Please Help and Suggest.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone -Core Plot problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484019/iphone-core-plot-problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but my guess is that what you see is not a shadow but a gradient fill generated by the use of "`tubularBarPlotWithColor`". The shadow is probably something outside the bar borders.

Instead, try creating the bar plot with:

```
CPBarPlot *barPlot = [[CPBarPlot alloc] init];
```

Then use:

```
barPlot.fill = [CPFill fillWithColor:myCPColor];
```

Or if you actually want a gradient fill:

```
fillGradient = [CPGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:myCPColorBegin endingColor:myCPColorEnd]; 
barPlot.fill = [CPFill fillWithGradient:fillGradient];
```

Hope this helps!
Claes

Comment: Thanks for reply.  here @ barPlot.fill = [CPFill fillWithColor:myCPColor]; if I give "greencolor" than it is displaying green color but if I take  "colorwithcomponentRed: green: blue: alpha "and it is showing bars in white color it is not taking any values for RGB color

Answer (score 0):

I faced the white colored plots isssue

yourPlot.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:80.0f / 255.0f green:186.0f / 255.0f blue:224.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

this gives me the desired color..